# Navicat - Beautiful SQL keyboard shortcut

Tags: navicat

Is there a short cut to Beautiful Query in Navicat ?

I could not find any in the documentation.

Still wondering, if there is any

Answer (score 3):

On macOS Sierra:

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. Select "App Shortcuts" from left side.
3. Click "+" under the right side.
4. In the popup, enter:

   - Application: Navicat (version).app
   - Menu Title: Beautify SQL
   - Keyboard Shortcut: Your preferred shortcut

This works on Sierra at least. I haven't checked other versions.